# Copy and insert modified strings into a vector without sorting

Tags: r, string

Let's say I have a vector of strings:

```r
vec <- c("D", "A", "B", "A")
```

I would like to insert a modified string (concatenate "_2" at the end of the strings) immediately after the original string, without sorting.

Expected output:

```r
[1] "D"   "D_2" "A"   "A_2" "B"   "B_2" "A"   "A_2"
```

I am looking for solutions simpler than the one I shared below, which I think could be unnecessarily over-complicated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `c` + `rbind` along with `paste0`

```
> c(rbind(vec, paste0(vec, "_2")))
[1] "D"   "D_2" "A"   "A_2" "B"   "B_2" "A"   "A_2"
```

or a longer version with `outer`

```
> c(t(outer(vec, c("", "_2"), paste0)))
[1] "D"   "D_2" "A"   "A_2" "B"   "B_2" "A"   "A_2"
```

---

If you don't mind the efficiency, you can try

```
> scan(text = gsub("(.*)", "\\1 \\1_2", vec), what = "", quiet = TRUE)
[1] "D"   "D_2" "A"   "A_2" "B"   "B_2" "A"   "A_2"
```

since `scan` might be slow when having long vectors.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use `vctrs::vec_interleave`:

```r
library(vctrs)
vec_interleave(vec, paste0(vec, "_2"))
#[1] "D"   "D_2" "A"   "A_2" "B"   "B_2" "A"   "A_2"
```

---

Or, add `"_2"` in every other element:

```r
paste0(rep(vec, each = 2), c("", "_2"))
#[1] "D"   "D_2" "A"   "A_2" "B"   "B_2" "A"   "A_2"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `sprintf` to concatenate the original and modified strings together with a symbol that you sure will not appear in the original strings, then split them and `unlist`.

```r
unlist(strsplit(sprintf("%s@%s_2", vec, vec), "@"))
[1] "D"   "D_2" "A"   "A_2" "B"   "B_2" "A"   "A_2"
```

Answer (score 1):

An option might be to `rep` vec and `replace` every second.

```
replace(rep(vec, each=2), c(FALSE, TRUE), paste0(vec, "_2"))
#[1] "D"   "D_2" "A"   "A_2" "B"   "B_2" "A"   "A_2"
```